# Syntax error in NMaximize despite following official documentation

Tags: mathematical-optimization, syntax, maximum

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
NMaximize[ {k, (a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k == 
     1) && (b + 2*c + 3*d + 4*e + 5*f + 6*g + 7*h + 8*i + 9*j + 10*k ==
      6) &&  (b + 4*c + 9*d + 16*e + 25*f + 36*g + 49*h + 64*i + 
      81*j + 100*k == 42)}, {a , b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, 
   k} \[Element] NonNegativeReals ]
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
NMaximize::ivar: (a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k)\[Element]\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]&&a>=0&&b>=0&&c>=0&&d>=0&&e>=0&&f>=0&&g>=0&&h>=0&&i>=0&&j>=0&&k>=0 is not a valid variable.
```

The syntax I'm using is NMaximize[{f,cons},x∈reg], which is suggested on the [official website](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html).

The f (function) part is just k, the "x∈reg" (region restriction) part is

```
{a , b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, 
       k} \[Element] NonNegativeReals
```

and the cons (constraints) part is

```
(a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k == 
         1) && (b + 2*c + 3*d + 4*e + 5*f + 6*g + 7*h + 8*i + 9*j + 10*k ==
          6) &&  (b + 4*c + 9*d + 16*e + 25*f + 36*g + 49*h + 64*i + 
          81*j + 100*k == 42)
```

So where's the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
NMaximize[{k, (a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k == 
     1) && (b + 2*c + 3*d + 4*e + 5*f + 6*g + 7*h + 8*i + 9*j + 
      10*k == 6) && (b + 4*c + 9*d + 16*e + 25*f + 36*g + 49*h + 
      64*i + 81*j + 100*k == 42),
  ## & @@ Thread[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k} >= 0]}, {a, b, c, d,
   e, f, g, h, i, j, k}, Reals]
```

```
{0.266667, {a -> 0., b -> 0., c -> 0., d -> 0., e -> 0.333333, 
  f -> 0.4, g -> 0., h -> 0., i -> 0., j -> 0., k -> 0.266667}}
```

And you can directly use `Maximize`, get

```
{4/15, {a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0, d -> 0, e -> 1/3, f -> 2/5, g -> 0, h -> 0, i -> 0, j -> 0, k -> 4/15}}
```

Comment: Now I get a new error: NMaximize::nonopt: Options expected (instead of \[DoubleStruckCapitalR]) beyond position 2 in NMaximize[{k,a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k==1&&b+2 c+3 d+4 e+5 f+6 g+7 h+8 i+9 j+10 k==6&&b+4 c+9 d+16 e+25 f+36 g+49 h+64 i+81 j+100 k==42,a>=0,b>=0,c>=0,d>=0,e>=0,f>=0,g>=0,h>=0,i>=0,j>=0,k>=0},{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k},\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules.

Comment: Thanks, using Maximize directly with what you wrote worked. I'm disappointed that 4/15 is the maximum, that's what I had before even using Mathematica and for the same exact assignment of variables. However, I'm impressed it managed to run the code so quickly (<1 second on my computer).

Answer (score 3):

`NonNegativeIntegers` is not a region,it is just a algebra field.

You can use

```
NMaximize[{k, a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k == 1, 
  b + 2*c + 3*d + 4*e + 5*f + 6*g + 7*h + 8*i + 9*j + 10*k == 6, 
  b + 4*c + 9*d + 16*e + 25*f + 36*g + 49*h + 64*i + 81*j + 100*k == 
   42}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k} ∈ 
  ImplicitRegion[
   Thread[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k} >= 0], {a, b, c, d, e, f, 
    g, h, i, j, k}]]
```

Or simpely

```
NMaximize[{k, a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k == 1, 
  b + 2*c + 3*d + 4*e + 5*f + 6*g + 7*h + 8*i + 9*j + 10*k == 6, 
  b + 4*c + 9*d + 16*e + 25*f + 36*g + 49*h + 64*i + 81*j + 100*k == 
   42, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k} >= 0}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, 
  h, i, j, k}]
```

Or

```
NMaximize[{k, a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k == 1, 
  b + 2*c + 3*d + 4*e + 5*f + 6*g + 7*h + 8*i + 9*j + 10*k == 6, 
  b + 4*c + 9*d + 16*e + 25*f + 36*g + 49*h + 64*i + 81*j + 100*k == 
   42, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k} ∈ 
   NonNegativeReals}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k}]
```

etc.